# Can I use a battery protection circuit for a 3S 18650 with a LiPo 3S pack?

Tags: lipo

I am looking into getting a battery protection circuit for the 3S LiPo pack I am planning on using in my project. Max current draw will be 5-6A. Since I think it's more efficient to buy something prebuilt I was looking on aliexpress for something that I could use.

However most of the parts sold there are specified as for 18650 battery pack usage. Here is an example:

[Protection circuit](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/3S-8A-11-1V-lipo-lithium-Polymer-BMS-PCM-PCB-battery-protection-circuit-board-for-3/32624738401.html)

Can I use this kind of circuit with a LiPo pack? Do I need to connect the battery + to B+, the battery - to B- and then connect 2 wires of the balance cables to B1 and B2, or am I completely wrong?

Since the circuit is rated a 8A it will be more than sufficient for my needs

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean for battery protection? What do you want it to do exactly? I don't read German so have no idea what this is. What are you wanting to actually do?

Comment: All the information you need is in the product description. The title  "3 S 8A 11.1 V **lipo lithium Polymer** BMS/PCM/PCB" and voltage specs tell you it is designed for Lipos, and the connection instructions tell _and show_ you how to wire the battery to it.

Comment: Protection for LI- cell packs always means the same: protect against undervoltage, overvoltage  and also against cell imbalance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not worry about the 18650 part of the spec. That's only a cell form factor.

If you have a Li-cell pack that brings out the cell balancing connections, then it'll be just fine. Your assumptions about how to connect it are correct.